# An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameter

Tags: c#, xpath, winappdriver

I'm using WinAppDriver. It works good, except to clicking a Yes\No button in a message box.

The Recorder UI gives this xpath:

> "/Pane[@ClassName="#32354"][@name="Desktop 1"]/Window[@name="TestCalc"][@AutomationId="YesNoMessageBox"]/Button[@name="Yes"][@AutomationId="Yes"]"

But when use it in my c# project, it doesn't work. I get the following exception:

> "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameter"

Can you please assist?

Comment: Were you able to locate the element with that XPath in the chrome dev tools window?

Comment: Is `Panel` your root element ? If that's not the case, use `//` at the beginning of your XPath expression. Are you dealing with namespaces  in your document ? Be sure to use single quotes around your XPath expression but double quotes inside it (or the invert).